# get timestamp (lastmodified) in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I want to get the last modified time of a file and save it in a variable using a vb script

Then I want to set the last modified time on another file to the same value as the variable.

Comment: Corrected the language and punctuation. However, don't feel this question is of sufficient quality for the site.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [.DateLastModified](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xh895w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property/attribute of the (object corresponding to the) file:

```
>> WScript.Echo goFS.GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName).DateLastModified
>>
22.11.2013 13:09:53
>>
```